# 12 two digit numbers. Show that at least two of them has a difference of the form aa

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Given 12 different two digit numbers. Show that at least two of them has a difference of the form aa.

Answer: Two digits equal each other in modulo 11.

I don't understand. Why modulo 11? How does that translate to a number of the form aa?
An example is 33 and 22. 33-22=11=aa

Comment: A number of the form $aa$ is a multiple of $11$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of The Pigeon Hole Principle.

Note that in $12$ different numbers, at least two of them will have the same remainder when divided by $11$. In other words, at least two of them equal each other in modulo $11$.

This implies that their difference is divisible by $11$. And since their difference is a two-digit number, it must be in the form $aa$.